# sort a nested json array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, nested

```
var dataSource = ({
"Items": ({
    "Deserts": ({}),
    "Veg": ({
        "VegPulao": "Veg Pulao",
        "PalakPaneer": "Palak Paneer",
        "PaneerButterMasala": "Paneer Butter Masala"
    }),

    "Chicken": ({
        "Tandoori": "Tandoori special"
    }),
    "Hot drinks": ({
        "Coffe": ({ "Hot": "Hot Coffe", "Medium": "Medium", "Others": ({ "Iris": "Iris Coffe", "Capuccino": "Capuccino" }) }),
        "Tea": ({ "Red": "Red Tea", "Black": "Black Tea" }),
        "Hot BadamMilk": "Hot Badam Milk",
        "Hot Bornvita": "Hot Bornvita",
        "Hot Milk": "Hot Milk"
    }),
    "Juice": ({
        "Mango": "Mango",
        "Berry": "Berry",
        "Grapes": "Grapes",
        "Wine": ({
            "Rose": "Rose",
            "Red wine": "Red",
            "Apple": "Apple",
            "Hard drinks": ({
                "Royal challenge": "Royal challenge",
                "Blender's Pride": "Blender's Pride"
            })
        })
    })
})

});
```

***Need to sort a nested json object 
like the one above?***

Comment: What's with all of the parentheses? Are they s'posed to be square brackets? (Also, that's not JSON. JSON is a string representation of data; there is no such thing as a JSON object.)

Comment: What do you mean sort a nested array?  If you remove the extra parens, these are nested objects and objects don't have a sort order.  I don't see any arrays.

Comment: sorry.. its a nested object only. i want it to be sorted..
any help

Comment: first remove those many misplaced (), it hurts my eyes

Comment: chk it 
http://vinoth-codings.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might have got the answer by now,

```
function rFun(obj, newObj){
    Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach(key=>{
        if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
            newObj[key] = {};
            newObj[key] = rFun(obj[key], newObj[key]);
        } else {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    });
    return newObj;
}

JSON.stringify(rFun(dataSource, {}));
```

it's sort by ASCII, for case insensitive you have to write custom sort.